# recreate new JS object for same python object

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I have two classes: ClassA and ClassB, both are written in python and exported to QML.

```py
class ClassA(QObject):
    bChanged = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._b = None

    @pyqtProperty(QObject, notify=bChanged)
    def b(self):
        return self._b

    @b.setter
    def b(self, val):
        self._b = val
        self.bChanged.emit()


class ClassB(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    # Do reference test in python
    @pyqtSlot(QObject, result=bool)
    def equal(self, ref):
        return self == ref


...

def main():
    # and I export them to QML by...
    qmlRegisterType(ClassA, 'CustomClass', 1, 0, 'ClassA')
    qmlRegisterType(ClassB, 'CustomClass', 1, 0, 'ClassB')
```

And I wrote three tests. One of the b property of ClassA object is assigned to QQuickRectangle

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import CustomClass 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 800
    height: 600
    visible: true

    ClassA {
        b: ClassB {
            id: bb
        }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            console.log('test 1:'+(this.b==bb).toString())
            console.log('test 2:'+(this.b.equal(bb)).toString())
        }
    }


    ClassA {
        b: Rectangle {
            id: rec
        }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            console.log('test 3:'+(this.b==rec).toString())
        }
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
Test 1: false
Test 2: true
Test 3: true
```

Is this related to the implementation of PyQT5? Current workaround that comparing python reference with additional slot is very inconvenient and inconsistant with the rest of QML code.

MRE can be found here
https://gist.github.com/tim37021/0f0decb68ba3d7183f840c5b0065cf43

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Sure, I just reproduce it a minute ago!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/tim37021/0f0decb68ba3d7183f840c5b0065cf43

Comment: Sorry, I've just miss the link for mre

Comment: Tim: please post all pertinent code here as an [edit] to your question, not in a link. The MRE needs to be small enough to be allowed in the question itself as code-formatted text, but complete enough to compile/run and demonstrate the issue. The link will explain all.

Comment: @TimHsu As HovercraftFullOfEels points out, the MRE should be in your question so edit your question and add it there.

Comment: @TimHsu 1) Provide the MRE in your question. 2) The link code has errors, such as *test2.qml:16: TypeError: Property 'equal' of object ClassB(0x55eff1597e30) is not a function* and *Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 46, in <lambda>
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(lambda: sig.stop())
NameError: name 'sig' is not defined*

Comment: @eyllanesc I've transformed the question into minimal form. And fixed the MRE code. sorry for that.

Comment: @TimHsu It seems to me that it is a pyqt5 bug since in pyside2 there is no such problem. I recommend reporting it.

Comment: thanks I noticed that too. I will send to their mailing list